# Timeout - App has not responded to the network requests below

Tags: react-native, expo, travis-ci, detox

**Goal**

Get detox tests to run with Travis for an Expo app.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode11.3

env:
  global:
  - NODE_VERSION=stable

install:
- brew tap wix/brew
- brew install applesimutils
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
- export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
- nvm install $NODE_VERSION
- nvm use $NODE_VERSION
- nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION

- npm install -g react-native-cli
- npm install -g detox-cli
- npm install -g expo-cli
- npm install detox

before_script:
- ./setup.sh

script:
- echo 'Starting expo in separate process'
- expo start --ios &
- echo 'Waiting on expo to start in other process and open an ios sim'
- sleep 300
- echo 'Running detox tests'
- detox test --configuration ios.sim --cleanup
```

**Error**

The Travis build failed with the following error -

```
detox[6787] INFO:  Example: should have welcome screen [FAIL]
detox[6787] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 2) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForAccessibilityID:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"firstScreen"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}
That might be the reason why the test "Example should have welcome screen" has timed out.
 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.spec.js (367.64s)
  Example
    ✕ should have welcome screen (243561ms)
  ● Example › should have welcome screen
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

In particular, any ideas about the following portion of the above error `App has not responded to the network requests below`?

**Project:**

Here is a link to the PR for the project https://github.com/bryanboyko/expo-detox-travis-3/pull/1

**Travis Build**

Full build logs - https://travis-ci.com/github/bryanboyko/expo-detox-travis-3/builds/152742315

**Steps to run detox tests locally**

- `git clone git@github.com:bryanboyko/expo-detox-travis-3.git`
- `cd expo-detox-travis-3`
- `git checkout bryan/travis`
- `npm install`
- `npm install -g expo-cli`
- `brew tap wix/brew`
- `brew install --HEAD applesimutils`
- `npm install -g detox-cli`
- `./setup.sh`
- `expo start --ios &`
- `detox test`

If possible, push a branch and create a PR to get a travis build going

Comment: I had the same issue with a non-expo react-native app. I resolved it by having detox build and test the release version instead of debug. Maybe the solution to your issue would be doing `expo start --ios &` in production mode, but I'm not sure how to do that.

[Here is my travis build if curious](https://travis-ci.com/github/osamaq/react-native-template/jobs/297418346/config)